# admob on custome surfaceView not loading ad

Tags: java, android, admob, surfaceview

Hi guys I am having problems loading admob on a custom surfaceview. From what I can tell I have followed the instructions correctly. But still no luck. Everything seems to work just fine without the surface view. I have seen a lot of advice for this topic and tried them all, setting sview below adview, seting adview background, doing it programatically aswell as hard coding the xml, changing adUnit id and so on, all my dependencies are up to date. Manifest file is also good but the ad simply does not load with surfaceview. In my log i see the "starting ad request" then "there wass a problem getting an ad responce errorCode: 0" and then "failed to load ad: 0".
By the way this is for a game I am developing. I am using an emulator and I am hoping that this is the problem but I don't want to risk uploading to market without sorting it out.

please help. Any advice will be very much appreciated.

Here is my code

```
private InterstitialAd interstitial;
private AdView adView;
private SView sView;
private static String unitId_Banner = "ca-app-pub------";   
private static String unitId_full = "ca-app-pub-------";    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId(unitId_Banner);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

    sView = new SView(this, this.getResources());

    RelativeLayout mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    mainLayout.addView(sView);

    mainLayout.addView(adView, adParams);

    setContentView(mainLayout);

    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build());
}
```

Starting ad request.

VFY: dead code 0x0028-0050 in Lcom/example/jjack/audio;. (Landroid/content/Context;)V

BEGIN 'ads28298.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
DexOpt: --- END 'ads28298.jar' (success) ---
DEX prep '/data/data/com.example.jjack/cache/ads28298.jar': unzip in 4ms, rewrite 1235ms

Could not find method java.io.IOException., referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.h

VFY: dead code 0x0035-0035 in Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient;.h (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/android/gms/common/a;

Could not find method java.io.IOException., referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getInfo

VFY: dead code 0x0040-0040 in Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient;.getInfo ()Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;

VFY: dead code 0x00dc-00f2 in Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/fv;. (Landroid/content/Context;)V

VFY: dead code 0x0103-0105 in Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/fv;. (Landroid/content/Context;)V

VFY: dead code 0x0019-001a in Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/gu;.evaluateJavascript (Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/webkit/ValueCallback;)V

There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0

VFY: dead code 0x00a9-00c1 in Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/ci;.a (Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/gu;Ljava/util/Map;)V

Failed to load ad: 0

thank you in advance

Comment: please post the logcat output.

Comment: done any ideas pleas